# Return Value of .save() in python Django like save in rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django

In Ruby on Rails we have

```
obj = Model.new
obj.el = "sample"
if obj.save
  puts "obj.save returns true"
end
```

so do we have anything like this in django like

```
user_obj = User(email='email@email.com', user_name='username', password='****')
if user_obj.save():
   print "will user_obj.save() returns anything?"
```

Does `.save()` return anything in Django and if so, what? How do I know whether `.save()` is a success or not?

Comment: Why don't you try it in the console and see what it returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the save fails, then it most likely will raise an error so you could use

```
user_obj = User(email='email@email.com', user_name='username', password='****')
try:
    user_obj.save():
except IntegrityError as ie:
   # fail
except ValueError as ve:
   # fail
print 'worked'
```

There is also a [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save) signal, that can be called after a successful save.